# Jackson De-serialization issue with - Should never call `set()` on setterless property

Tags: spring-boot, lombok, jackson-databind, fasterxml

Problem described as below,

Dependencies used:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I have a pojo which is part of bigger domain object and is exposed to certain end point,

```
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Value
public class SomeStatus {

    @NonFinal
    @Builder.Default
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<InvalidReason> statusReasons = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<InvalidReason> getInvalidReasons() {
        return statusReasons.stream()
                .filter(invalidReason -> invalidReason.getSeverityLevel().equals(SeverityLevel.INVALID))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
    public Set<InvalidReason> getHints() {
        return statusReasons.stream().filter(invalidReason -> invalidReason.getSeverityLevel().equals(SeverityLevel.HINT))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
    public boolean isValid() {
        return CollectionUtils.isEmpty(getInvalidReasons());
    }
}
```

What I need here is , I don't want to expose `statusReasons` but I have created getter methods such as `getInvalidReasons` and `getHints` which then should be exposed with respective endpoint.

I have following Json test case which is failing,

```
@Test
public void someStatusJsonTest() throws Exception {
    SomeStatus status = random(SomeStatus.class);
    String string = om.writeValueAsString(status);
    SomeStatus readBack = om.readValue(string, SomeStatus.class);
    assertThat(readBack, is(status));
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.ValueInstantiationException: Cannot construct instance of `com.bosch.dras.sbf.domain.SbfStatus`, problem: Should never call `set()` on setterless property ('hints')
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 1538260] (through reference chain: com.bosch.dras.sbf.domain.DeliveryOption["sbf"]->com.bosch.dras.sbf.domain.Sbf["sbfStatus"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.ValueInstantiationException.from(ValueInstantiationException.java:47)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.instantiationException(DeserializationContext.java:1758)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleInstantiationProblem(DeserializationContext.java:1128)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.wrapInstantiationProblem(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1769)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeUsingPropertyBased(BeanDeserializer.java:492)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1322)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:331)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:164)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:542)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeWithErrorWrapping(BeanDeserializer.java:535)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeUsingPropertyBased(BeanDeserializer.java:419)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1322)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:331)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:164)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:542)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeWithErrorWrapping(BeanDeserializer.java:535)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeUsingPropertyBased(BeanDeserializer.java:419)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1322)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:331)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:164)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4526)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3468)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3436)
    at com.bosch.dras.sbf.domain.DeliveryOptionTest.test(DeliveryOptionTest.java:30)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Should never call `set()` on setterless property ('hints')
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.SetterlessProperty.set(SetterlessProperty.java:147)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.PropertyValue$Regular.assign(PropertyValue.java:62)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.PropertyBasedCreator.build(PropertyBasedCreator.java:211)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeUsingPropertyBased(BeanDeserializer.java:490)
    ... 86 more
```

I must admit I am not much into whats happening under the hood when seriliazation de-seriliazation happens.

I tried with some options available in SO to explicitly mentioning @JsonProperty and @JsonIgnoreProperties(allowSetters = true) but none of them solved my issue. Lack of experience with this scenario is stopping me from applying other solutions as well.

Hint:- If I remove `@JsonIgnore` from `statusReasons` attribute everything works fine. I do understand there is some dependencies between them but unable to reach the roort cause.

Any further help is highly appreciated. Do let me know in case I need to provide more details.

Update:

```
public enum InvalidReason {

    MISSING_SOMETHING_FOR_AN_ENTITY(SeverityLevel.INVALID),       
    INCOTERM_NOT_STANDARD(SeverityLevel.HINT),    
    CUSTOMER_NOT_SPECIFIED(SeverityLevel.INVALID),    
    WAREHOUSES_NOT_MATCHING(SeverityLevel.INVALID);

    @Getter
    private final SeverityLevel severityLevel;

    InvalidReason(SeverityLevel severityLevel) {
        this.severityLevel = severityLevel;
    }
}

public enum SeverityLevel {    
    INVALID,
    HINT,
}
```

Comment: Can you share the class InvalidReason and the random method

Comment: I have added the classes. Regarding random I am just using `EnhancedRandom` from dependency `<dependency><groupId>io.github.benas</groupId><artifactId>random-beans</artifactId>
<version>3.7.0</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>`  to create new instance with random values. we can create the object by our self.

Comment: I can not reproduce the issue, it looks like something is missing in your question. I get Cannot construct instance of `.SomeStatus` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)

Comment: Did you also use Lombok annotation for boilerplate code as in `@Value` in my example which internally equivalent to `@Getter @FieldDefaults(makeFinal=true, level=AccessLevel.PRIVATE) @AllArgsConstructor @ToString @EqualsAndHashCode`. If you don't have Lombok you might use IDE to generate these and then try.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce you issue, but maybe this will help https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/2692

Comment: If you could download Lombok and integrate I hope you can reproduce the issue. I will check and provide necessary information to reproduce it without Lombok. Thank you for your inputs.

Comment: I have a project with Jackson 2.11.0 and lombok 1.2.3, but still can't reproduce

Comment: The error seems related to the fact that jackson see your `getHints` getter desuming there is a hints property and check if there the setHints setter method not finding it, then the error.

Comment: Well, you cannot remove the one core information (`statusReasons`) from your serialized JSON and then expect that deserializing will work. Jackson cannot magically invert the logic in your getters.

Comment: @JanRieke My use case is I don't want `statusReasons` to be part of serialization and I believe it should be possible . Any inputs towards it would be helpful.

Comment: You have to write setter methods or a constructor for the "virtual" fields (`hints` and `invalidReasons`) that Jackson can use to reconstruct your objects.